# How does file reader work in this code

Tags: servlets, filereader

`

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException 
    {  
            response.setContentType("text/html");  
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();  

            String name=request.getParameter("name");
            String file=request.getParameter("file"); 



                        Session session=factory.openSession();
                        session.beginTransaction();

                        File f=new File(file);

                        byte[] imageData=new byte[(int)file.length()];


                        try
                        {
                            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
                            fileInputStream.read(imageData);
                            fileInputStream.close();
                        }
                        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

                        ENtity image=new ENtity();
                        image.setImageName(name);
                        image.setData(imageData);

                        session.save(image);
                        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }
```

`
Can anyone tell how the image is being stored in the above code.
the program is developed with hibernate capabalities and i want to know how does the image is being stored using byte of arrays.